# wanting to make sql calls update json files

Tags: sql, node.js, json, azure

I am using some JSON files to store some data that I am using in a web page, nothing crazy just using node, express, and pug HTML templating engine. Now what I am wanting to do is have a page that can update an azure sql database table, and use this page to also run a few select commands to update my JSON files. 
Now I am using a regular old Azure database, server combo, and i can connect to it wit Microsoft SQL server management studio and make select call, specifically one such as:

```
select name as [name], price as [price], description as [description]
from food
where iType='le'
for json path, root('allfood');
```

This gives me the JSON output I want, but I am trying top make a button on my page start that SQL call and then save the output to a JSON file.
Is this possible?

Edit: to explain a bit of what i am trying to do.
so i have this index.js file

```
const sql = require('mssql');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const allfood = require('./public/json/food.json');

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

const sqlconfig = {
    server: "[myserver info]"...

}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    var conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(sqlconfig);
    var sqlreq = new sql.Request(conn);

    conn.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        sqlreq.query("select * from specialsView, eventsView", function (err, hometext) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                res.render('index', {
                    homeText: hometext.recordset
                })
            }
            conn.close();
        });
    });
});

app.get('/tapList', (req, res) => {
    var conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(sqlconfig);
    var sqlreq = new sql.Request(conn);

    conn.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        sqlreq.query("select * from tapListView", function (err, taplist) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                res.render('taplist', {
                    tapList: taplist.recordset
                })
            }
            conn.close();
        });
    });
});

app.get('/lunchM', (req, res) => {
    var conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(sqlconfig);
    var sqlreq = new sql.Request(conn);

    conn.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        sqlreq.query('select * from lunchEntreesView as "lunch.e" for json path select * from lunchSoupSaladView as "lunch.ss" for json path select * from lunchSidesView as "lunch.s" for json path', function (err, lunche,lunchss,lunchs) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                res.render('lunchMenu',{
                    lunche: lunche.recordset,
                    lunchss: lunchss.recordset,
                    lunchs: lunchs.recordset
                  })
            }
            conn.close();
        });
    });
});

const server = app.listen(7000, () => {
    console.log(`Express running → PORT ${server.address().port}`);
  });
```

where i use express, mssql, and pug to render pages with data from my azure database, no prob for the one page there, but now i am wanting to separate some data from the table, hence those three sql queries on the same line that was a lame attempt at what i want. the output for those three sql queries gives me json

```
[{
    "name": "The Ollie",
    "price": "8",
    "description": "A Quarter Pound Burger Served on a Pretzel Roll with Spring Mix, Roma Tomato, Red Onion & Colby Jack Cheese-With Choice Of Side"
}, {
    "name": "The Ollie",
    "price": "8",
    "description": "A Quarter Pound Burger Served on a Pretzel Roll with Spring Mix, Roma Tomato, Red Onion & Colby Jack Cheese-With Choice Of Side"
}, {
    "name": "The Ollie",
    "price": "8",
    "description": "A Quarter Pound Burger Served on a Pretzel Roll with Spring Mix, Roma Tomato, Red Onion & Colby Jack Cheese-With Choice Of Side"
}, {
    "name": "The Ollie",
    "price": "8",
    "description": "A Quarter Pound Burger Served on a Pretzel Roll with Spring Mix, Roma Tomato, Red Onion & Colby Jack Cheese-With Choice Of Side"
}]
```

which is nice but it would be cool if i could some how get it to make query those three view and sort it more like

```
{
  "lunche": [
     {data....}
   ]
  "lunchss": [
     {data....}
   ]
  "lunchs": [
     {data....}
   ]
}
```

Pointers, or links to point me in the right direction would be dope. Thanks!

Comment: It's possible but not directly from JavaScript in a web page. You need some server side code on a webserver as well. Sounds like you've got node JS on your server side so you should be able to do it from there

Answer (score 0):

As ADyson mentioned, you will need to complete this in your Node backend instead of directly from the front end.

Take a look at [tediousjs](https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious) for connecting to Azure SQL from Node JS. You can also use this quickstart to try implementing it with Azure SQL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-nodejs

```
function queryDatabase()
{
    console.log('Reading rows from the Table...');

    // Read all rows from table
    var request = new Request(
        "select name as [name], price as [price], description as [description]"
        + "from food"
        + "where iType='le'"
        + "for json path, root('allfood');",
        function(err, rowCount, rows)
        {
            console.log(rowCount + ' row(s) returned');
            process.exit();
        }
    );

    request.on('row', function(columns) {
        columns.forEach(function(column) {
            console.log("%s\t%s", column.metadata.colName, column.value);
        });
    });

    connection.execSql(request);
}
```